# ZF2 Form : In controller action request is never POST even if it should

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2, admin, zend-form, http-post

I've got an issue with forms in ZF2. This is a login for a temporary admin session I try to set up, and after submitting form it seems the request is never in POST method. I tried to add

```
$this->setMethod('post');
```

But it doesn't work either. How can I get $request->isPost() to be true ?

My loginAction in Controller :

```
public function loginAction()   {
         $form  = new AdminForm();
         $form->get('submit')->setValue('Login');

         $request = $this->getRequest();
         if ($request->isPost()) {
             $form->setData($request->getPost());
             if ($form->isValid()) {
                if (md5($form->get('password')->getValue())==foo)   {
                    $_SESSION['foo']='foo';
                }
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin');
             }
         }

         return array(
             'form' => $form,
         );
     }
```

My Form :

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Form;

 use Zend\Form\Form;

 class AdminForm extends Form
 {
     public function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct('admin');
         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'password',
             'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Password',
            ),
         ));


         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'submit',
             'type' => 'Submit',
             'attributes' => array(
                 'value' => 'Go',
                 'id' => 'submitbutton',
             ),
         ));
     }
 }
```

My login page :

```
<?php

 $title = 'Login';
 $this->headTitle($title);
 ?>
 <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
 <?php

 $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('admin', array('action' => 'login')));
 $form->prepare();

 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
 echo $this->formCollection($form);
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your form to POST, you need to set it up as so. Add:

```
$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
```

to your form class constructor, then give it another try.

Comment: Okay this is really weird since I'm pretty sure I tried this one as well as $this->setMethod('post');
But now it's working, I must have mistyping something. Many thanks